# User-entered (javascript) regex to mysql regexp

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex, node.js

I'm receiving an html input regex string and passing it to node.js which formulates a mysql query this way:

```
var sql = "SELECT id, text FROM data WHERE text REGEXP " + 
      connection.escape(regex_string);
```

I should be set for the security side (I'm escaping the user-entered string), but the problem is that mysql uses different metacharacters than the ones I'm used to (e.g. the space `\s` is `:space:` for mysql): http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

How to make javascript-entered normal regular expressions understandable by mysql REGEXP queries?

Comment: This is a very hard problem, mainly because the regular expression language is quite large and also security. Is it enough to offer a subset of the language? like only support simple matches like `abc.*` and `[a-z]{5}`?

Comment: My only idea would be to write a function which uses the replace method with a regular expression over your regex_string variable. But that can be a huge effort because there are a lot of different escape signs

Comment: I doubt there is anyone here who can write a conversion function for you. You need to do it on your own. Here is JavaScript regex reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Halcyon it is, at least the mysql ones would be preferable.

Comment: Teach the users to write _mysql_ regexps?